# How to smooth already made slope?

Tags: modeling

I have made this slope manually but I was wondering how to smooth it out because it is clearly bumpy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete most of the edge-loops in between. That will make your life much easier. You can probably only keep the lower two as well as the upper two. Add one on the middle to adjust the arc. Subsurf should do the rest.